# Excel VBA "Subscript out of range" Run Error '9'

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried to implement the following code so that I can read a cell value and then places this value into another cell on the same Worksheet.

The worksheet has the following name: TestUserGuidance (Has no spaces)
The code is as follows:

```
Sub GuideTest()
    Dim dblPower, dblMass, dblRatedSpeed, dblRefLength, dblAwot, dblEngineSpeed, dblRoadSpeed As Double
    Dim dblPMR As Double

    dblPower = Worksheets("TestUserGuidance").Cell("B1").Value
    Worksheets("TestUserGuidance").Cell("E1") = dblPower
End Sub
```

Could anyone please advise where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: This question is duplicate, I just answered the exact same question a week ago.

Comment: If you click debug, what pat of your code is highlighted?

Comment: There is no `Worksheets.Cell` I guess you mean `Worksheets.Range`. And declaring `Dim dblPower, dblMass As Double` will only declare the last one as `Double` but the first will remain `Variant` instead declare a type for **every** variable like `Dim dblPower As Double, dblMass As Double, …`

Comment: @SilentRevolution  I have amended how i have declared the dblMass etc and that is fine..

The code that is giving me the problem now is:

dblPower = Worksheets("TestUserGuidance").Range("B6").Value ??

Comment: I think Dave Thornton's answer is the right solution. There should be no reason for the error with the code you've provided. It is however recommended to avoid things as `selection` and `active`. `Worksheets("TestUserGuidance")` is the same as `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TestUserGuidance")` but may not necessarily be the same as `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TestUserGuidance")` especially when you have multiple workbooks open.

Answer (score 2):

I think vba can't find  the TestUserGuidance sheet. If I run the following in the immediate window I get an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error:

```
?worksheets(1).cell("A1")
```

If I run this, I get the error you mention "Subscript out of range":

```
?worksheets("non-existent sheet").cell("A1")
```

This suggests to me that the active workbook is incorrect since you would have gotten the other error if vba was able to find the worksheet. Can you try adding ThisWorkbook (and also use range)?

```
dblPower = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TestUserGuidance").Range("B1").Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TestUserGuidance").Range("E1") = dblPower
```

Another option would be to rename your worksheet:

[image]

Then you won't have to worry about the active workbook (and also get intellisence):

```
shtTestUserGuidance.Range("E1") = shtTestUserGuidance.Range("B1")
```

Also, I would suggest you make all the corrections suggested by others. You will likely have other issues moving forward otherwise.

Lastly, if the worksheet is like a template and the structure won't change, you'd be better off just using a formula (i.e. E1's formula: =B1). Even if there's conditional logic, it might be easier to maintain as a formula rather than vba code.

Here are some troubleshooting steps:

Toggle a break point on the line where dblPower is set by clicking on the grey area to the left:
[image]

Also open the Immediate window if it's not already there by pressing ctrl+g:
[image]

When you run the code, it should pause at the break point. Now you can inspect what's in scope. Try typing the following into the Immediate window and press enter:

```
?Worksheets("TestUserGuidance").Name
```

or

```
?ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

Note that you can also step through the code line by line by pressing F8 while the cursor is somewhere within the subroutine. Bottom line is that you may need to examine the code line by line in order to figure this out.

Comment: What I mean is that another workbook could be active. If the worksheet existed (in scope that is), the op should have gotten a different error. Subscript out of range occurs when you're trying to access something from an array or collection that does not exist. I don't see anything else in his code that could produce that error.

Comment: Makes sense, indeed. Although `Awot Model` is the name of both the VBEditor and the Excel file.

Comment: Unfortunately, we're working with limited info here. Maybe put a break point on that line where dblPower  is being set. Then when the break point is hit, run ?activeworkbook.name or ?Worksheets("TestUserGuidance").name in the immediate window.

Comment: @DaveThornton I have now tried the code in a blank Excel file and it has worked perfectly but do not understand why it wont work in my existing file?

Comment: I added some troubleshooting steps to my answer that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to make your code working:

```
Sub GuideTest()
    Dim dblPower, dblEngineSpeed, dblRoadSpeed As Double ' first two are of variant type
    Dim dblPMR As Double

    dblPower = Worksheets(1).Range("B1").Value
    Worksheets(1).Range("E1") = dblPower
End Sub
```

When you use "E1" or "B1" you should use `Range`, not Cells. In my answer `Worksheets(1)` refers to `Worksheets("TestUserGuidance")`.

Comment: But with `Dim dblPower, dblEngineSpeed, dblRoadSpeed As Double` only `dblRoadSpeed` is of type `Double` the first 2 are `Variant` but they start with `dbl` so I guess all of them should be `Double` like:  `Dim dblPower As Double, dblEngineSpeed As Double, dblRoadSpeed As Double`

Comment: Uhm, I see no comment of the OP (Keiron Morris) in this whole question and answers. But anyway your comment made it clear :)  It's just I always see these wrong declarations and most people would think all of them will be double then.

Comment: `Worksheets(1)` will not necessary refer to `TestUserGuidance` sheet.

Comment: @DavidG. - of course not. But it is easier for me this way to replicate.

Comment: Then you should put a comment about it. You can get the OP more confused.

Answer (score 0):

Only `dblRoadSpeed` is declared as double.
To fix it, declare all your variables as individual, in vba you can do in 2 ways.

```
Dim dblPower As Double, dblMass As Double
```

Or

```
Dim dblPower As Double
Dim dblMass As Double
```

Also, you don't need to declare any variable to do what you are doing.
You can copy the value in one step.

```
Worksheets("TestUserGuidance").Range("E1").Value = Worksheets("TestUserGuidance").Range("B1").Value
```

Comment: I thought of that, but would it generate an error since the variables are declared as variant which can hold anything?

Comment: @SilentRevolution In this specific case, `Variant` variables will not cause any error, but it can cause some run time errors if you try to compare some variables or you pass this variable to a function or procedure that needs an specific variable type.

Comment: I was just referring to this particular question. But it is best practice to always declare all variable and use `Option Explicit`

Comment: @DavidG. I have also tried the method you have given. However, it is now highlighting that line is causing the problem??

Comment: @KeironMorris, I'm at work and not able to see images, not sure what are you trying to achieve. Can you provide more information? Also, what Office version and OS are you using? I tested the line in my machine and works like a charm!